# Entity Framework many-to-many relationship error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have two classes:

```
public class Cluster
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Blob> Blobs { get; set; }
}

public class Blob
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cluster> Clusters { get; set; }
}

public ClusterConfiguration ()
{
    this.HasKey(p => p.Id)
        .HasRequired(p => p.Frame)
        .WithMany(p => p.Clusters)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.FrameId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true)
        ;

    this.HasMany(p => p.Blobs)
        .WithMany(p => p.Clusters)
        ;
}

public BlobConfiguration ()
{
    this.HasKey(p => p.Id)
        .HasRequired(p => p.Frame)
        .WithMany(p => p.Blobs)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.FrameId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true)
        ;

    this.HasMany(p => p.Clusters)
        .WithMany(p => p.Blobs)
        ;
}
```

There are references to other tables in these classes but I do not think that is the problem. The error is:

`[{"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ClusterBlobs_dbo.Blob_Blob_Id' on table 'ClusterBlobs' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.\r\nCould not create constraint. See previous errors."}].`

I'm not quite sure how to tell EF to cascade delete Blobs if Clusters are deleted but not to delete Clusters if Blobs are deleted. Please advise.

UPDATE: Using EF5 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple cascading delete path is actually in effect if you delete a `Frame`, not a `Cluster` or `Blob`:

- `Frame` is deleted -> Cascades to `Clusters` -> Cascades to link table
- `Frame` is deleted -> Cascades to `Blobs` -> Cascades to link table

So, these are the two paths from `Frame` to the link table.

I would suggest to disable cascading delete for one of the two (or both) relationships from `Frame` to `Cluster` or `Blob`. (Use `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` there.) Disabling cascading delete for the link table is not possible on an individual relationship basis. The only way is to disable the convention globally:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

But this will affect *all* many-to-many relationships in your model.

> I'm not quite sure how to tell EF to cascade delete Blobs if Clusters
>   are deleted but not to delete Clusters if Blobs are deleted.

This is by the way not possible. There is no cascading delete between `Cluster` and `Blob` because from database viewpoint the many-to-many relationship is actually modeled with two one-to-many relationships with the link table in between. Cascading delete only acts on the link table which is the dependent in the relationships. `Cluster` and `Blob` are both principals.

Comment: Thank you @Slauma. I wrote an ORM way back for myself and assumed that it would be easy to report an EF level error rather than relay the underlying constraint error which is generated from the database. `[Disabling cascading delete for the link table is not possible on an individual relationship basis].` I am assuming that is a database level restriction rather then EF. Also, I should have thought of the fact that cascade delete does not apply to normalized many-to-many relationships. It's just that the identity of these two objects is not well defined in my model so far.

Comment: By the way, since cascade delete is only available for one path, what is the most appropriate place to write some manual deletion code for the other path?

Comment: @RaheelKhan: Yes, it's a DB level (SQL Server) restriction. For other DBs it might work without exception. I believe EF has no idea about delete paths. Most appropriate place will depend on your architecture. If you have (non-generic) repositories maybe in a Delete method for `Frame`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that turning off `ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention` globally is not a wise option. Instead, it's better to turn it off *only for the concerned* table.

This can be achieved through editing the generated migration file, for property **`cascadeDelete`**. For example:

`AddForeignKey("dbo.ClusterBlobs", "Blob_Id", "dbo.Blob", "Blob_Id", cascadeDelete: false);`